# I have some errors while installing yajl-ruby in windows

Tags: ruby, rubygems, command-prompt

Hello I'm trying to install ruby in windows, I installed all the gems but I couldn't install yajl-ruby when I run teh following command : 
`gem install yajl-ruby`.
It gives me this error :
    `Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...`
`Building native extensions.  This could take a while...`
`ERROR:  Error installing yajl-ruby:`
       `ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

`current directory: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.3.0/ext/yajl
C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170617-12896-vt754k.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile`

`current directory: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.3.0/ext/ya
jl
make "DESTDIR=" clean
'make' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.`

`current directory: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.3.0/ext/yajl`
`make "DESTDIR="
'make' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.`

`make failed, exit code 1`

`Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/yajl-r
uby-1.3.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.4.0
/yajl-ruby-1.3.0/gem_make.out`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your MSYS/MINGW installation doesn't contain the `make` utility.  Did you install it?